# Why is it best practice to ignore binary files?

Tags: git, svn

I know its a good practice to ignore binary files. But whats the main importance of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary files are usually not written directly by a human being, they tend to be generated from some kind of a source. It's far better to store the source, because it's usually textual and changes in it are easier to display using the standard tools like `diff`. You can always generate the binary file again from the source.

Comment: Of course, unless we are talking about an image, photo, and many other files where the binary is the source ;)

Comment: @ochi: Sure, but how often do you want to track changes in a photo, and also, in how many of these cases the changes are again binary in their nature?

Comment: I just meant to indicate that a) binaries are not always generated from 'source' b) the question is too broad and the answers are nuanced.  They depend on which binaries we are talking about, which projects/cases, even which policies/regulations are in place, etc.

Mostly, we do want to know which version of a 'binary' is being used (i.e. two different versions of the same logo) and, agreed, we are not that interested in seeing the changes in between versions so the premise that it's a 'good practice to ignore binary files' is a bit biased, imho

Comment: I used the word "usually" which, according to my limited knowledge of English, my third language, bears the meaning of "not always".

Comment: Pedantry aside, you have a point.  However, you also used the phrase "You can always generate the binary file again from the source" which, as any of you three languages could tell you, it's what I was referring to in point (a) above.

Answer (score -1):

A more general question and answer to this can be found here:

[Is it good practice to store binary dependencies in source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674006/is-it-good-practice-to-store-binary-dependencies-in-source-control)

For binaries that are not generated from your source, you may still need to keep these in your repo. If that is the case, consider using LFS for these files. With LFS, the repo has a pointer stored in the commit that references the binary. When you clone, git will retrieve the LFS files for that commit also.